# how to call a button with id in javascript and how to apply loop?

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```
 <script>
(document).ready(function(){
("button").click(function(){
("p").toggle();
});
});
</script>
and
<button style="width:80%;" > </button>
```

i want to call this button by id instead of "button" on above javascript and also want dynamic id like loop.. which increment itself according to database.

Comment: Please define "_call a button_". You mean you want to get a reference to that button?

Comment: And where is jQuery (the `$`)?

Comment: THIS CODE IS WORKING FINE THIS IS SCRIPT.. I ONLY WANT TO REPLACE THE "BUTTON" WRITTEN IN SCRIPT WITH ID AND ALSO WANT TO CREATE THE ID OF BUTTON

Comment: [There you go](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) ... The ID  stuff should be done at server-side.

Comment: i removed $ because stackoverflow is not accepting it... you are not understanding my question.... i want to say that on the click of button this code is working perfect but i have to use so many buttons in the same page i want different id of each button and also it should be auto generated and how can i call different ids of different buttons in the same code????